# Filtering in formulas in Excel

Tags: excel

I am aware of the `SUMIF` (and friends) formula. I am wondering if it's possible to extend the logic to other functions (e.g. "maximum age where gender=F") without macros or VBA. I tried things like

```
MAX(IF(A1:A5="F",B1:B5,""))
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you have multiple criteria you should read this [DDOE post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/03/23/maxif-and-minif-with-multiple-variables/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with an array-formula, use `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to enter this formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A5="F",B1:B5,0))
```

(it will display in the formula-bar with curly-brackets).

The zero is used for those values/rows that aren't "F", which won't affect the maximum age.

Comment: .but this question should be in superuser.com because you don't require any coding. This is a programming forum.

Comment: @AndyG Not saying your comment is wrong, but a serious question, I am very used to people redirecting questions to SuperUser, yet on [Excel Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info) page it seems to imply that questions for Formulas are exceptable if tagged as `Excel-Formula`

Comment: My bad, I was missing the Ctrl-Shift-Enter bit. Thanks! (edit: yes, `cmd`+`enter` works too!)

Comment: @user2140261 It says that `Excel-formula` is a "more specific tag". A question should be about programming but could include this tag to indicate that it specifically relates to a formula, perhaps using VBA to insert a formula into a cell. Someone more senior might clarify my understanding. It is true, though, that many formula (non-programming) questions are still answered here - mainly when they are straight-forward, and it causes less hassle to just answer them :)